# How to catch Exception in split-join catchAll on OSB?

Tags: oracle, service, soa, osb, bus

I want to catch exception in split join but the fault variable is empty and it is not showing any exception .
Kindly give me any solution so I can catch and log it.

Regards,
Junaid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to do easily. That's why I use [Generic Parallel](http://genericparallel.com/download/) and let it do the hard work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Can you please give me the link how to use Generic Parallel. because i have downloaded zip file and dont know how to use it in OSB11g.

Comment: You import it into OSB like any other OSB service. Then, you construct an xml message that specifies the endpoint(s) you want GP to hit and the payload(s), and any settings you want. Then you route the message to the generic parallel proxy service and it will do its thing and return a response for you to transform, or throw a fault if it encounters an error (or not - how it handles errors is based on the settings you sent it during the request)

Comment: Thank u I will try and let you know

Comment: Well, to catch the actual fault you need to call a proxy from split-join, and not a Biz service. This is how GenericParallel does it.

Comment: For my project, I added an sb-transport proxy that routes to the local GenericParallel proxy so I could point bizrefs at it. Does that make a huge difference?

Comment: @TrentBartlem, not sure what is your question :-) Email me if you still need to get an answer.